# jQuery serialize doesn't work with cloned form after input value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, clone

I have a form with text input fields. One of the input fields is called greetings and its value is 'Hello World'.

```
var $form = $('[name="form"]');
var $greetings = $form.find('[name="greetings"]');
console.log($greetings.val()); // prints 'Hello World'
```

Using jQuery I clone this form.

```
var $formToSubmit = $form.find(':not([data-dont-submit=true])');
var $formClone = $formToSubmit.clone();
```

Then I change value of the greetings input and check if it worked.

```
var $clonedGreetings = $formClone.find('[name="greetings"]');
$clonedGreetings.val('Goodbye');
console.log($clonedGreetings()); // prints 'Goodbye'
```

When I serialize the cloned form, the output has the old value of the greeting input field.

```
console.log($formClone.serialize()); // prints ...greetings=Hello+World
```

**Why** is this happening and **how** can I make it serialize the modified value?

Full code below:

```
var $form = $('[name="form"]');
var $formToSubmit = $form.find(':not([data-dont-submit=true])');
var $formClone = $formToSubmit.clone();
var $greetings = $formClone.find('[name="greetings"]');
$greetings.val('Goodbye');
console.log($greetings.val()); // prints 'Goodbye'
console.log($formClone.serialize()); // prints ...greetings=Hello+World
```

**UPDATE:**
I found out that another selector that happens before the form cloning is causing the issue. This selector is excluding some of the inputs from further processing and Ajax request. The input field I'm modifying doesn't have this attribute set to true and therefore is not excluded.

`var $formToSubmit = $form.find(':not([data-dont-submit=true])');`

I didn't expect this to have any influence, that's why I initially omitted the line. Please see update code.

Comment: The cloned form is an independent object, so it keeps the values that it had when it was created. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would it keep those when I change it after the cloning? I need to change the value in one of the input fields before serializing the form and sending it as Ajax.

Comment: `$form` and `$formClone` are two separate forms. You change the value in the first, not in the second. It's not clear to me why you are cloning the form at all, but if you really need to serialize and send the clone, then clone it after the changes.

Comment: Maybe what you don't realize is that this is a deep copy. So the clone of the form contains clones of all the inputs.

Comment: Apologies, there was a mistake in the code. Now it's fixed. Better read the "Full code below" part.

Comment: Your updated code works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/vu1et04L/

Comment: Looks like the issue was in a line, I didn't expect to have any effect at all. Please see update.